# Ionic 2 Launch.json: Attribute ‘program’ does not exist “path”

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm unsuccessfully trying to run the 'Launch Program' debug mode of my Ionic 2 app.
I'm getting the error `"Attribute 'program' does not exist"` followed by the path where app.ts is supposed to be. 
By default, my launch.json looks like this:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\app.ts",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "outFiles": [],
    "sourceMaps": true
},
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Process",
    "port": 5858,
    "outFiles": [],
    "sourceMaps": true
}
]
```

The thing is, I've searched my directories and I can't find "app.ts" anywhere. I've tried replacing this file by several others but the error stays the same.
Also, I've been willing to use the Cordova Tools extension. The installation worked fine but my launch.json's configurations wasn't updated (I don't know if that's normal) so i had to search the internet for a configuration to try to "Run Android on device" for instance.
Here's how the configuration for this launch mode looks like;

```
{
    "name": "Run Android on device",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "type": "cordova",
    "request": "launch",
    "platform": "android",
    "target": "device",
    "port": 9222,
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

I'm getting this error

> Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?
>   'ionic run android --device --verbose' failed with exit code 1

I'd be grateful for any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you have the `ionic.config.json` file in the root of your project? It seems to be missing. Take a look at this repository: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base Your app structure should more or less look like that one.

Other than that I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. Are you just trying to run a simple ionic2 project? Because I have never seen or heard of a `launch.json` file.
Do you use VSCode? To rule out any errors in your VSCode configuration I would run/build the app from the command line first. Try running it by executing `ionic serve` in the terminal/command prompt.

EDIT:

What version of ionic2 are you using? I don't think there is an `app.ts` anymore.

Comment: I have the ionic.config.json and my project's structure looks similar to the one on the repositery you've linked.
ionic serve works fine, i can launch my app without any problem.
I use VSCode and i'm simply trying to debug my app/launch it in debug mode.
My ionic version is 2.1.17 (the latest) and yes app.ts doesn't appear to exist anymore... Yet it is the default file used in the "program" field of launch.json's configuration.
launch.json is the file that tells VSCode's debugger in which launch mode it should debug. You can find it in ..\MyApp\.vscode\launch

Comment: Ah, I have never had to debug a cordova plugin, the js console was usually enough for me. Did you try to change `"program":"${workspaceRoot}\\app.ts",` to `"program":"${workspaceRoot}\\src\\app\\main.ts",`?

Comment: It throws another error: `Cannot launch program 'path' setting the outFile attribute might help`.
Right now the outFile attribute looks like this: `"outFiles": []` (check my post for the full configuration)

Comment: I'm sorry, then I don't know what else you can do. Maybe it's a bug in vscode? And just to be sure: You are trying to debug a cordova plugin and not your app (javascript), right?

Comment: No, i'm trying to debug my app, running on my Android device (or anywhere else, but that's why I need it for)

Comment: Did you try remote debugging? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: I haven't, I will have a look right now. But I still don't get why VSCode's debugger throws errors. Same goes for Cordova Tools, it's supposed to be installed & working in 2 minutes

Comment: Remote debugging works quite fine thanks! Do you know if it's possible to use breakpoints ?

Comment: You should use be able to use breakpoint just like when debugging in chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131131/discussion-between-clementino36-and-andreas-gassmann).